# Emitting db2ts command via JDBC

Tags: jdbc, full-text-search, db2

Some of my DLL statements related to full text search (ex: CREATE INDEX...FOR TEXT) only run when executed from db2ts. I'd like to emit these statements directly from some java code using JDBC, but then an SQL syntax error is returned.
Is there a way to emit these commands from JDBC?

Answer (score 0):

Actually, you have to call the admin proc in SYSPROC to do the job. The documentation is not that clear but I've been able to delete an index by using:
CALL SYSPROC.SYSTS_DROP('DB2ADMIN','TESTS_FTS_FT','en_US',?)